# How would I test a JS function with Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, testing, jestjs

New to JS, Express, Node, Jest... But as a project, we were given a new unfamiliar code base and we're suppose to add some functionality to it including some testing. The code currently has this function in order to create a new `User` on signUp;

```
// Create
export async function create(parentValue, { name, email, password }) {
  // Users exists with same email check
  const user = await models.User.findOne({ where: { email } })

  if (!user) {
    // User does not exists
    const passwordHashed = await bcrypt.hash(password, serverConfig.saltRounds)

    return await models.User.create({
      name,
      email,
      password: passwordHashed
    })
  } else {
    // User exists
    throw new Error(`The email ${ email } is already registered. Please try to login.`)
  }
}
```

This is my test that I'm trying to get to pass, but I'm having difficulties even passing the function the information

```
import { create } from './resolvers.js'
import models from '../../setup/models'

describe("user resolvers", () => {
  test("creating a user", () => {
    expect(create({name: "test", email: "test@example.com", password: "123456"})).toMatchObject(models.User)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to use async/await if you want to get created user instance from DB. you can use mocking alternatively. Another point `toMatchObject` methods expect class instance/object as argument.Try as below:

```
test("creating a user", async (done) => {
  const attributes = {name: "test", email: "test@example.com", password: "123456"};
  const { name, email } = await create(attributes);
  expect(attributes).toMatchObject({ name, email });
  done();
});
```

**NOTE**: Remove `parentValue` argument from the `create` method if it is no longer need to you

Comment: I don't entirely know what the parentValue is doing, but I made the changes and they make sense - but I'm still getting an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` which still leads me to think it's not passing the attributes through correctly.

Comment: if you have already removed `parentValue` and your method looks like `... function create( { name, email, password })` then you need to check if you have `name` property in your model and DB. And please check if it created a new record in your user table.
you don't need to have **await** keyword here: `return await models.User.create`